# plist not copied to bundle

Tags: ios, plist, bundle

I have a few plist in my project, and I have added them to the target and "Copy bundle resource".

For some reason, they do not get copied to the app package.
I looked into the package content of the app in the simulator, everything but the plist files is copied.

(They are not in sub-directory; they are directly in the Resources group)

I tried cleaning, reinstalling..

Why is that?

**Turns out there are some null scripts in my project build rules which block the plist files from being copied over!**

Comment: Have you given target membership to those plist? check it once.

Comment: yes, they do have the correct target membership

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out there are some null scripts in my project build rules which block the plist files from being copied over!

Comment: Can you tell me what you changed please? I am having the same issue! Many thanks :D

Comment: Look at the project build rules, make sure there aren't null scripts. That was my problem, you should probably try delannoyk's suggestions first. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Check that the file is copied in the bundle resources by :

1/ Clic your project name in Xcode,

2/ Go to your target name,

3/ Build Phases,

4/ In the "Copy Bundle Resources", check that your plist is added.

If not, add it with the "+" button.

Comment: They have all been done.. Also, if I change the extension to not plist, it works/ gets copied to the bundle